# Counting fields in a group by, and generating a greport with ms access

Tags: sql, t-sql, ms-access

So I have this table

```
City       | Status   | District | Revenue
------------------------------------------
Oakland    | Executed | North    | $9.50
Los Angeles| Cancelled| South    | $0.05
Oakland    | Executed | North    | $0.99
Oakland    | Cancelled| North    | $98.40
Sacramento | Executed | North    | $43.50
Sacramento | Cancelled| North    | $5.40
Los Angeles| Cancelled| South    | $5.30
```

So I need this report that reads like this:

```
North District | Executed | Cancelled | Revenue
--------------------------------------------------------
Oakland        |     2    |      1    |   Sum of revenue
Sacramento     |     1    |      1    |   Sum of revenue
--------------------------------------------------------
South District | Executed | Cancelled | Revenue
--------------------------------------------------------
Los Angeles    |     0    |      2    |   Sum of revenue
```

But I'm stuck on how to create a query that groups and counts instances of specific values inside that group.

I mean I know syntax of group statements and count statements, but the counting a specific number of instances of a row inside a group seems pretty different than a regular count.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction? I'm not asking anyone to do my work (this isn't even a full sample of what I have to do) but if someone can help me with a statement that groups and counts specific rows in the group, with a SQL statement or an Access function, that would be awesome. From there I'd be able to figure out everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I ran across an answer actually. I just had to use Sum(IIF()) and it worked correctly.

```
SELECT
Test.City,
=Sum(IIf(Status="Cancelled",1,0))
FROM Test
Group BY Test.City
```